# Kubernetes Pod Oubound Traffic DNAT rule

Tags: networking, kubernetes, nat, calico

We run **K8S** cluster in private network behind firewall with nasty reverse NAT rules that prevent our hosts to connect to themselves over public IPs.

**Problem**

From inside a pod I need to connect to the service that is resolved to public IP `203.X.X.X` that is not possible. However I can connect to this service over private IP `192.Y.Y.Y`

I can setup **iptables** rule on the node running pod as follows:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p tcp -d 203.X.X.X --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.Y.Y.Y:80`

Then I can successfully connect to the service from node, but not from pod running on this node.

Solution with **hostAliases** would not work as we:

- do not know the host names in advance
- would like to reroute all traffic to known public (unreachable) IPs to the respective private IPs

PS:
We use calico as networking plugin

Comment: Anton, have you manage to find the issue already?  Which exactly k8s you are tunning?  Is it some minikube, etc?  how did you install it?  "From inside a pod I need to connect to the service that is resolved to public IP 203.X.X.X"  what is the need for that?  could you show svc config (`kubectl get svc <name> -o wide`)?

Comment: this has been solved by adding same rules to PREROUTING chain